# Consulta con un proc en SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

estoy haciendo un sistema de búsquedas en C# y tengo un problema con mi consulta de Sql Server, estoy tratando de hacer una busqueda que me pueda filtrar Nombre del proveedor, los recursos y números sinad de mi tabla proveedor.

```
CREATE PROC SP_REPORTES
@TEXTOBUSCAR VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  COD_PROV AS 'Código',
    SIA_PROV AS 'SIAF',
    NOM_PROV AS 'Proveedor',
    COD_UE AS 'UE',
    NOR_PROV AS 'N° Orden',
    COD_OFICINA AS 'Oficina',
    SID_PROV AS 'SINAD',
    SIG_PROV AS 'SIGA',
    FEC_PROV AS 'FECHA',
    COD_TAREAS AS 'TAREAS',
    REC_PROV AS 'RECURSOS',
    COD_UM AS 'U. DE MEDIDA',
    COD_FF AS 'FF',
    COD_CLASIFICADOR AS 'CLASIFICADOR',
    CAN_PROV AS 'CANTIDAD',
    MON_PROV AS 'MONTO UNITARIO',
    MOT_PROV AS 'MONTO TOTAL',
    FEC_INI AS 'FECHA INICIO',
    FEC_FIN AS 'FECHA FIN',
    OBS_PROV AS 'OBSERVACIÓN',
    DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(day,15,FEC_PROV)) AS 'Expira',
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))=1 THEN 'PLAZO VENCIDO'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))>=2 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))<=6 THEN 'POR VENCER'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))>=7 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))<=13 THEN 'EN PROCESO'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))>=14 AND  DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY,15,FEC_PROV))<16 THEN 'GENERADO'
    ELSE 'CONCLUIDO'
END AS 'Movimiento'
FROM TB_PROVEEDOR
WHERE SID_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%'
ORDER BY COD_PROV ASC
END
GO
```

En la parte del where cuando le agrego esta linea:

```
WHERE SID_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' AND NOM_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' AND REC_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%'
```

No me llega a filtrar bien en mi textoBox, uso un textChange de evento

```
this.dgvDatos.DataSource = 
clsReportes.SP_REPORTES(txtDatos.Text.Trim().ToUpper().ToString());
```

Le agregaría 3 radiobuttons para que busque Proveedor, Sinad y Recursos? o se podría hacer todo en uno solo? Lo estoy haciendo en C# desktop

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, filtra bien solo el primer paramentos SID_PROV pero ya no llega a filtrar los otros dos parámetros NOM_PROV Y REC_PROV

Answer (score 1):

Aunque lo ideal sería que le pasases el tipo de búsqueda, siempre lo puedes simplificar con un cambio mínimo (cambio el `AND` por el `OR`).

```
WHERE SID_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' OR NOM_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%' OR REC_PROV LIKE '%' + @TEXTOBUSCAR + '%'
```

De esta forma buscará resultados de las tres búsquedas posibles.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder muy rápido, ya modifique el AND por el OR y me funciono como quería, muchas gracias. Roger.